# Append Text To Drop Down Option Populated from DB

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a page within an MVC application that contains a drop down box that allows the user to select a from a number of financial periods.

For the purposes of making it clearer for our users, I'd like to append "(Current)" to the option that is the current financial period and potentially "(Latest)" to the previous period to represent the last full period. We can already determine which financial period we are in and subsequently the one previous and so on.

So let's say the two options I'm looking to append to currently look like this:

- Period 11
- Period 12

and I'd like it them to read:

- Period 11 (Latest)
- Period 12 (Current)

The drop down is populated from a database, but I would like to append this text at the application level.

Is this something that is possible? If so, how? I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to go about it.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you always know that Period 11 is "Latest" and that Period 12 is "Current?"  Or are those dynamic values?  If dynamic, do you always know that the strings take the format of "Period" + <int>?

Comment: They're always dynamic, and yes, they are always in the format of Period <int>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using some sort of `IEnumerable` on your model/view model class to populate the items in the drop-down.  When you construct this list, simply add your "(Current)" and "(Latest)" options before returning the model to your view.  If `FinancialPeriod` is a model/view model class like this:

```
public class FinancialPeriod{
    public int FinancialPeriodId { get; set; }
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could do this in your controller, assuming that your list of all Financial Periods retrieved from the database is a property on your model called `FinancialPeriods`:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var model = GetTheModel();
    model.FinancialPeriods.Add(new FinancialPeriod{ 
        FinancialPeriodId = <something>, 
        DisplayText = "(Current)"
    };
    model.FinancialPeriods.Add(new FinancialPeriod{
        FinancialPeriodId = <somethingElse>
        DisplayText = "(Latest)"
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Make sure you substitute values for `<something>` and `<somethingElse>` that you can interpret correctly when the model is posted back to your controller.

**Edit - based on your comments and edits, something like this is more appropriate:**

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    var model = GetTheModel();
    var currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;
    var previousMonth = currentMonth - 1;
    if (previousMonth == 0)
        previousMonth = 12;
    var currentPeriod = "Period " + currentMonth.ToString();
    var latestPeriod = "Period " + previousMonth.ToString();
    var newList = new List<FinancialPeriod>();
    foreach(var period in model.FinancialPeriods){
        if(period.DisplayText == currentPeriod)
        {
            newList.Add(new FinancialPeriod
                { 
                    FinancialPeriodId = period.FinancialPeriodId,
                    DisplayText = period.DisplayText + " (Current)"
                };
                continue;
        }
        if(period.DisplayText == latestPeriod) 
        {
            newList.Add(new FinancialPeriod
                {
                    FinancialPeriodId = period.FinancialPeriodId, 
                    DisplayText = period.DisplayText + " (Latest)"
                };
            continue;
        }
        newList.Add(period);
    }
    model.FinancialPeriods = newList;
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't particularly clear in my question. The options already exist within the drop down, let's say as Period 11 and Period 12.

I'd like to append to the display text of those options so that they read Period 11 (Latest) and Period 12 (Current).

Comment: Oh.  Do you always know that Period 11 is "Latest" and that Period 12 is "Current?"

Comment: No, that's just my example. It changes month to month, so our next current period would be within our new year, so Period 1 would become Period 1 (Current) and Period 12 would be come Period 12 (Latest).